# Missing semicolons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm not recognized to JavaScript that much, but I need to include my
header to my HTML. We have a contact form provided from our work place and need to imply to my header.

But I've been having an missing semicolons errors, and I don't know which place it is.

```
function writeHeader(){
    var html = "";
    html += '<header>';
    html += '<p class="fL mr15"><a href="javascrip:openWin('002','10100');"><img src="images/head_btn01.png" alt="contact" class="opacity"></a></p>';
    html += '</header>';

    document.write(html);
}
```

This part won't actually work: `<a href="javascrip:openWin('002','10100');">`

Comment: `javascrip` is a typo...

Comment: `javascrip:openWin('002','10100');` See that? javascrip? Besides, we have no clue whether openWin is defined (also, ' should be escaped in such a case)

Comment: so sorry. this is js for openWin

Comment: function openWin(rShohincd,rShozokucd){

 document.frm01.hidShohincd.value  = rShohincd;
 document.frm01.hidShozokucd.value  = rShozokucd;

 wx = 660;
 wy = 650;
 x  = (screen.width - wx) / 2;
 y  = (screen.height - wy) / 2;
 winShozoku = window.open('','WindowP','left='+x+',top='+y+',width='+wx+',height='+wy+',menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,resizable=no');
 winShozoku.focus();

 document.frm01.method = 'post';
 document.frm01.target = 'WindowP';
 document.frm01.action = 'purai.asp';
// document.frm01.action = 'purai.asp';
 document.frm01.submit();
}

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the single quotes in your string:

**Change this:**

```
javascrip:openWin('002','10100')
```

**To This:**

```
javascript:openWin(\'002\',\'10100\')
```

You also spelt wrong "javascript".

Comment: hi, thanks for the corrections. but it still wont work>< I'm really confuse about it...sorry

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the problem? Are you seeing any errors in your browser console after the function gets executed? By the way, make sure the function is being called.

Comment: when i tried to execute your functions, no errors written in the console.

Comment: actually I don't see any errors to my console, but the contact form wont work properly. the only errors shown is missing semicolons ... ><

Comment: Where are you seeing this error "missing semicolons"? Does it tell in which line the error occurred?

Comment: before fixing it with your functions, both saw it on browser and text editor. Now, I wont see any errors but the contact form wont work properly...btw, i also write down this tag on my index.html <form name="frm01" action="" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="hidShohincd" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="hidShozokucd" /> 
</form>

Comment: this is the js for openWin

Comment: function openWin(rShohincd,rShozokucd){
document.frm01.hidShohincd.value = rShohincd;
document.frm01.hidShozokucd.value = rShozokucd;
wx = 660;
wy = 650;
x  = (screen.width - wx) / 2;
y  = (screen.height - wy) / 2;
winShozoku = window.open('','WindowP','left='+x+',top='+y+',width='+wx+',height='+wy+',menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,resizable=no');
winShozoku.focus();
document.frm01.method = 'post';
document.frm01.target = 'WindowP';
document.frm01.action = 'https://..purai.asp';
//document.frm01.action = 'http:/..purai.asp';
document.frm01.submit();
}

Comment: In your function there's a line that is setting the action URL `document.frm01.action = 'https://..purai.asp'`. It doesn't look right to me. I don't know what is the right URL, but try removing "https://.." `document.frm01.action = 'purai.asp'`. If it doesn't work please provide more information about the problem. What happens when the form gets submitted?

Comment: I just removed the right link to shortcut it because the company name is shown on the link. after the script has been submitted, the contact forms open but the right form title cant be seen.　The values for the title will be the ('002','10100'). But the html that i included wont read ('002','10100') as a value but it consider as a string or empty values.

Comment: I ran locally the code you sent through and it looks right to me. Perhaps there's a problem in 'purai.asp' where the values are being read.

Comment: I see..thanks a lot! I'll try to find out the problem about purai.asp! sorry for bothering ><